# Remove Default Modules to ContentPane

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have limited knowledge on DNN, I designed new skin,container for pages and I can able to create pages with new skin. 
But While create new page, there are few modules are automatically added to  "contentPane" place holder. 
Do you have any information about how to remove these automatically added modules to contentpane? (FYI, I am using latest DNN version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that modules are automatically added:

1. By default, the HTML module is added to every page.  When you create the page, there is an option that shows the HTML modules selected.  Before you create the page, just delete that module from the list.
2. There is a module option in DNN that says, "Add this module to EVERY page".  You need to find out which modules are getting added and change that setting in that module.

Comment: In terms of #1) this happens when you create a page using the Default template, you could create a page without the default template, or modify the template, if you want to change the number of modules loaded.